# Error - The relative virtual path 'Site.Mobile.Master' is not allowed here

Tags: argumentexception

I am receiving below error, how can I resolve?

Earlier it was working fine in subfolder of domain. But when I uploaded it in root, it has produced this error:-

Server Error in '/' Application

"The relative virtual path 'Site.Mobile.Master' is not allowed here"

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The relative virtual path 'Site.Mobile.Master' is not allowed here.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLKvo.png)

I tried all the solution I got on Google, nothing worked.